# Calculate the volume of a 3D List

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, regions

so I have this set:

$B= \{(x,y,z)\mid\mid x\mid\leq2,\mid y  \mid\leq 2 ,\mid x*y\mid\leq1, 0\leq z\leq2-\mid x\mid\}$

and I want to calculate the volume, but I have no idea how to define such an set.

Comment: Have you seen `ImplicitRegion[]`?

Comment: Ah, I did not know that this exists. Now it is working. Thank you.

Comment: Could you post the awnser to your own question?